# Can't play video on my iPhone when I upload it to dropbox via Python

Tags: python, video, upload, dropbox

I'm new to python and currently playing around with pytube. I wanted to download a Youtube Video to then upload it to my Dropbox-Account. The Down- and Uploading part works fine, but if I access the same file on my iPhone, it's an object file and I can't play it as a video. On PC, it works fine.
Here's the code

```
import pathlib
from pytube import YouTube
import dropbox

yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8LrSIIqNYg")

stream = yt.streams.get_by_itag(18)
title = yt.title + " - " + yt.author
stream.download(output_path=r"C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\Zug-Videos", filename=title)


dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("MY-Access-Token")

try:

        local_file_path = pathlib.Path(r"C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\Zug-Videos") / title

        with local_file_path.open("rb") as f:
            meta = dbx.files_upload(f.read(), "/"+title, mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode("overwrite"))

except Exception as e:
        print('Error uploading file to Dropbox: ' + str(e))
```

Comment: The file(s) extension?

Comment: I did also try it with `file extension = "mp4"` but it didn't work either